# When primary DC fails, secondary won't act as a backup (all users lose connectivity)

Tags: domain, windows-server-2012-r2

I have 2 DC's. When PDC fails, the secondary DC won't act as a backup (all users lose connectivity to LAN and WAN: domain network turns to unidentified until PDC is brought back online again.

Global Catalog box is checked on all DC's

Data gets replicated properly to all 3 DC's (we have 2 more at another site)

Where else should I look?

Comment: Are the clients configured to use the secondary DC as their secondary DNS server?

Comment: Yes. There are 3 DNS IP's. Primary DC, secondary DC and one more DC at another site